# Javascript – return multiple values to chained "then" functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have a fetch call with a couple of *then* functions. In one of the *then* functions I'd like to pass two returned variables to the next *then* function. It doesn't work though.

```
.then(text => { 
  let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html"); 
  let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML; 
  let title = content.querySelector('title').innerHTML; 

  function thehtml() { 
    return { 
      main, title 
    }
  } 
}) 
.then(thehtml => { 
  let theParsedHtml = thehtml(); 
  document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = theParsedHtml.main; 
  document.title = theParsedHtml.title; 
})
```

Accessing the thehtml() function in the last *then()* throws a *is not a function error*. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Your first `then` callback does not `return` anything.

Comment: Hm, I'm trying to return the *main* and *title* variables. Do I have to return the whole *thehtml()* function somehow to be able to reference it in the next *then()*?

Comment: Actually you don't even need the function. Just return something like `[ main, title ]` or `{ main, title }` to have access in the next `then()` function. (Or use `await/async` to get rid of the `then()` functions altogether.)

Comment: @ToE You're returning them from the `thehtml` function. You're not returning anything from the `then` callback function. The `thehtml` parameter of the second `then` callback is `undefined`.

Comment: If I return `return { main, title }` and in the next function access it in `document.title = title;` it says that `title` cannot be found though.

Comment: the next `then()` should accordingly look like `.then( (parsedHtml) => { document.title = parsedHtml.title; /* ... */ }` or using a destructuring statement  `.then( ({title, main}) => { document.title = title; /* ... */ }` .

Comment: Thanks @Sirko, this worked (I used your second suggestion)! It makes sense to me but I don't know why your first suggestion works since *parsedHtml* is not defined anywhere. Shouldn't *parsedHtml.title* throw a not found error?

Comment: `then()` basically defined a callback that is executed when the previous promise is resolved and by itself returns a promise resolved with its returned value. The value that promise resolves to, is passed on as a parameter to the callback of the next `then()`. So like any other function can name their parameters whatever they like, the same holds true for the callbacks to `then()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code like below, through which you can get access to the `title` and `main` in the other `then` method.

```js
.then(text => { 
  let content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html"); 
  let main = content.querySelector('main').innerHTML; 
  let title = content.querySelector('title').innerHTML; 

  return { 
    main, title 
  }
}) 
.then(thehtml => { 
  document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = thehtml.main; 
  document.title = thehtml.title; 
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe explain why this works although *thehtml* is not defined anywhere before. Shouldn't *thehtml.main* say that it can't be found?

Comment: The returned data from the first `then` will be the parameter for the next `then`, so there's no need of defining `thehtml` anywhere in the code. Whatever the data being returned from first `then` will be captured with the object named `thehtml` and it can be named anything as per the convenience.